# Sails.js populate filter

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, sails.js

I am trying to get all of my posts' comments which comments count is greater than 0. I am tying to add the where in find and populate, but none of it worked.

Post model:

```
module.exports = {
  attributes: {
    user: {
      model: 'user'
    },
    comments: {
      collection: 'comment',
      via: 'post'
    }
};
```

PostController:

```
Post
  .find({comments: {'>': 0}, user: me})
  .populate('comments')
  .exec(function(err, comments){
    res.json(comments);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

In current Sails/Waterline relations implementation you can't filter by one-to-many related fields. You need to filter the result after `find` is completed.